# PHP - Bypass Short URI Using curl

Tags: php, curl

Hello i want to bypass short link URL using curl. Foe example `www.bypass.com/8765` this link hide `www.example.com` how to bypass this and get hidden link.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/cGTgb2");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Opera/9.80 (Series 60; Opera Mini/6.5.27309/34.1445; U; en) Presto/2.8.119 Version/11.10');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,"cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,"cookie.txt");                               
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: bypass.com is not a valid domain ! please provide a valid one to be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at source code gives me the following

```
<noscript>This site requires JavaScript and Cookies to be enabled. Please change your browser settings or upgrade your browser.</noscript>
```

and the javascript as

```
try {  
    location.reload(true);  
} catch (err1) {  
    try {  
        location.reload();  
    } catch (err2) {  
        location.href = getHostUri();  
    }  
}
```

which tells me that the redirection is based on js code. Now curl can only be used to fetch the content. I might recommend using `phantomjs` or `selinium` to get the link after execution of js.